# red5 server not starting

Tags: red5, openmeetings

Hello I am having problem with red5 server starting. The server is not starting. When i run the red5.bat on command prompt in windows7 then the it stops with the following error:

```
Exception org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creatin
g bean with name 'red5.common' defined in class path resource [red5.xml]: Instan
tiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstan
tiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.context.
support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext]: Constructor threw exception; nested ex
ception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creati
ng bean with name 'org.springframework.jmx.support.ConnectorServerFactoryBean#0'
 defined in class path resource [red5-common.xml]: Invocation of init method fai
led; nested exception is java.io.IOException: Cannot bind to URL [rmi://localhos
t:9999/red5]: javax.naming.CommunicationException [Root exception is java.rmi.Co
nnectIOException: non-JRMP server at remote endpoint]
```

Please i really need help with this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: it seems that you already have one application using the port 9999